# Searching for the right SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql table called messages, where i receive all messages from various devices.

The structure is (start_time is a unique key):

[image]

explanation: first remove all duplicates from one session and then sum all quantities.

I will be very thankful for your help

Comment: Duplicates based on which of the columns?

Comment: see the image description. duplicates of products

Comment: start_time can't be a unique key!!! A unique key provides a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns. Your column start_time has repeated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query. It should do it.

```
select t.product, sum(t.quantity) as sum_quantity
from
(
    select distinct product, quantity
    from
    messages
) t 
group by t.product
order by t.product asc
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend, this was a real life saver :D works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a group by with a distinct

```
Select Product, Sum(Distinct Quatity) As Qty
From messages
Group By Product
```